# Highlight unique values based on another range

Tags: vba, excel, highlight, vlookup

Column 1 is in Sheet1 and column 2 is in Sheet2. If the value is not found , then highlight that cell. I am trying to do a vlookup comparing two columns. I think the **Syntax is incorrect**.  Please see my code I was trying below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub VlookupColoums()
   ' declarations
    Dim lookFor As Range
    Dim srchRange As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim vtest As Variant
    ' start
    Set lookFor = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13").End(xlUp)
  Set srchRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").End(xlUp)
  vtest = Application.VLookup(lookFor.Rows.Count, srchRange.Rows.Count, 2, False)
    ' process
   For I = 1 To lookFor.Rows.Count
    If IsError(vtest) Then
srchRange.Interior.Color = 4
Else
Exit Sub
End If
Next I


End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with conditional formatting with a `countif` inside? Any particular reason for using a complicated and strange VBA macro?

Comment: how will the conditional formatting work in such a case?

Comment: Very well, actually. :) Give me a minute, let me write up an answer.

Comment: Do you want to highlight cells on Sheet1 or Sheet2? Highlight cells with **no** match on the other sheet?

Comment: Highlight in sheet 2. Highlight cells with no match on the other sheet

Comment: This code is pretty far from working, conditional formatting is faster, cheaper and shinier. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have data on Sheet1!A1:A15 and Sheet2!A1:A10.

Also assuming you want to highlight unique cells (ones withouth at least one identical in the other list) on Sheet2.

Basically you want to format all the cells that if counted on the other list comes up with 0. The steps:

1. Select all the cells to be evaluated on Sheet2
2. Go to `Home`/`Styles`/`Conditional Formatting`
3. Select `New Rule`, then `Use a formula to determine...`
4. Enter this formula: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,A1)=0`
5. Click on the Format button, and set up a formatting for the unique cells
6. OK
7. Profit. :)

[image: Conditional formatting]

Comment: @James Cool, glad I could help. Mark it as answer then? :)